# Fastest way to access middle four elements in Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a Numpy array, such as

```
rand = np.random.randn(6, 6)
```

I need the central four values in the array, since it has axes of even length. If it had been odd, such as 5 by 5, then there would only be one central value. What is the simplest/fastest/easiest way of retrieving these four entries? I can obtain them very crudely with indices, but I'm looking for a faster way than calling a bunch of functions and performing a bunch of calculations.

For example, consider the following:

```
array([[ 0.25659355, -0.75456113,  0.39467396,  0.50805361],
       [-0.77218172,  1.00016061, -0.70389486,  1.67632146],
       [-0.41106158, -0.63757421,  1.70390504, -0.79073362],
       [-0.2016959 ,  0.55316318, -1.55280823,  0.45740193]])
```

I want the following:

```
array([[1.00016061, -0.70389486],
       [-0.63757421,  1.70390504]])
```

But not just for a 4 by 4 array - if it is even by even, I want the central four elements, as above.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question. Can you just not use `rand[1:5,1:5]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is something like this too complicated?

```
def get_middle(arr):
    n = arr.shape[0] / 2.0
    n_int = int(n)
    if n % 2 == 1:
        return arr[[n_int], [n_int]]
    else:
        return arr[n_int:n_int + 2, n_int:n_int + 2]
```

Comment: No, this makes sense, but like I said, I can do the same - with a bunch of calculations and calling functions and whatnot. Is there a faster way?

Comment: I think that any other way would in the background call the same code. You can keep this code tucked away, call it and forget about the surface implementation!

Comment: I'm only worried about time because this function will probably get called as many as ~10^3-10^4 times throughout the script, so we'll see

Comment: Creating a random array of size 11x11 and running the code 10e5 times took 364 ms. Also the code is made in such a way to not get slower with array size so I think you should probably be fine!

Comment: I agree with @JulesTamagnan, you won't have performance problems.  In modern computing 10^4 iterations of something this size is not much at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a single slicing operation:

```
rand = np.random.randn(n,n)
# assuming n is even
center = rand[n/2-1:n/2+1, n/2-1:n/2+1]
```

I'm abusing order of operations by leaving out the parens, just to make it a little less messy.

Answer (score 1):

Given array a:

> ```
> import numpy as np
> a = np.array([[ 0.25659355, -0.75456113,  0.39467396,  0.50805361],
> [-0.77218172,  1.00016061, -0.70389486,  1.67632146],
> [-0.41106158, -0.63757421,  1.70390504, -0.79073362],
> [-0.2016959 ,  0.55316318, -1.55280823,  0.45740193]])
> ```
>
> The easiest way to get the central 4 values is:
>
> ```
> ax, ay = a.shape
> a[int(ax/2)-1:int(ax/2)+1, int(ay/2)-1:int(ay/2)+1]
> ```

This works if you have even numbers for the dimensions of the array. In case of odd numbers, there won't be a central 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use indexing? Like:

```
A = np.array([[ 0.25659355, -0.75456113,  0.39467396,  0.50805361],
[-0.77218172,  1.00016061, -0.70389486,  1.67632146],
[-0.41106158, -0.63757421,  1.70390504, -0.79073362],
[-0.2016959 ,  0.55316318, -1.55280823,  0.45740193]])
])

A[1:3,1:3]
```

Or if matrix A had odd dimensions, say 5x5 then:

```
A[2,2]
```

Comment: I think you are right, but op explicitly asked for not using indices.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Sorry, still new at this.